# Would a charged capacitor react differently to a continuity test than a discharged?

Tags: capacitor, multimeter

I'm testing my non-reacting circuit with a multimeter, but I don't know if I have to discharge my capacitors first or not. I use two capacitors: 0,1 uF and 560 pF.

Comment: If a cap has real continuity (not just fooling the meter), then it probably won't be charged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but with caps that small it should not make a difference.  Generally your meter measures continuity by applying a small current and then measuring the voltage drop.  A short circuit will produce a very small voltage drop.  If you connect a large capacitor that's discharged, this current will charge up the cap.  As a result, it might take a while for the voltage on the cap to rise above the 'short circuit' threshold, so the meter may read the cap as a short circuit for some time while the cap charges up.  This will only be noticeable if your cap is at least 100 uF or so.  If the cap is already charged, then the meter might just read the cap as 'open'.  However, I would be careful about measuring large charged capacitors in continuity check mode as it is possible that they could damage the meter and/or give you a nice shock.  With caps smaller than 1 uF, it won't make much difference, and they were probably already discharged by the circuit anyway.

Comment: First, just to be safe,discharge the cap(s).

Comment: So if my 560pF cap doesn't respond to a continuity test, it is probably broken?

Comment: @SimonRavelingien What do you expect from a healthy capacitor, what should be the continuity test result (resistance)?

Comment: I guess a healthy one should give a noise?

Comment: For a cap less than 1 uF, I  would not expect the meter to read it as a short long enough to beep.

Comment: So than it is normal that my multimeter doesn't make a noise?